# How To Echo Multiple MYSQL result if One Query carry Null Result?

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I am new in PHP. I have a code in which i fetch record fro db. I Use multiple SQL queries in it according to my need. Here i have a problem. My One query carry ZERO Row, Mean have no data in db against that query. When i run my code nothing is displayed on my browser page. I want that the query which have data will be displayed and the query which have no data will be ignored.

Here is my code

```
  <?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pacra1";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM  `pacra_client_opinion_relations` 
WHERE  `client_id` =97 LIMIT 1";

$sql1 = "SELECT * 
FROM  `pacra_client_opinion_relations` 
WHERE  `client_id` =97 LIMIT 1,1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
echo $row ['creation_date'];

echo '<br>';

    echo $row1 ['creation_date'];
} }

?>
```

Second SQL query carry NULL result

Can you please help me how i can print my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are fetching data from multiple statements intermingled. You need to ensure that you get all the data you need from one query before you start the second query.

```
$row1 = $conn->query($sql1)->fetch_assoc();
$row2 = $conn->query($sql2)->fetch_assoc();

echo $row1 ['creation_date'];
echo '<br>';
echo $row2 ['creation_date'];
```

As long as you know that you only have one row in each result, this will work very well.

Comment: In my question there is sample queries. Actually i have 5 queries

Comment: Simple is that... Let Suppose i have a query which fetch record from db against any id.. Some id have 2 rows some have 3 rows and some have 5 rows. I use LIMIT 1,1 to fetch 2nd row, LIMIT 2,1 to fetch 3rd row... ...!!!! To fetch each row separately i use separate query. Lets suppose an id which have only 2 rows an i use the query to fetch 3rd row then its mean my query will be empty. When my query is empty it will not display the result of other two quries

Comment: But your queries are not stating **the goal** of what you are trying to do. You are simply saying "I am trying to read from 5 tables at once", but I am asking "Why? What do you need it for?" :)

Comment: My goal is to fetch record of a table one by one row. Fetch record first row then 2nd row and so on...!!!

Comment: Please check out my updated question. I update my queries. Now lets suppose My second query which have LIMIT 1,1 target directly second row in db is empty. How can  ignore my this query and will be able to print the data of first query